# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un juego de probabilidad, cuando uso el método sin retornar el objeto del array me da todo sin errores (únicamente el num), al agregarle la parte de findItem para obtener desde el id el nombre de lo ganado, me da el error, o me tira que es undefined en la consola. El metodo que me da problemas es probabilidad()

```
class Prize{
constructor(data){
    this.id = data.id
    this.nombre = data.nombre
    this.img = data.img
    this.articulo = data.articulo
    this.cantidad = data.cantidad
    this.categoria = data.categoria
}
probabilidad(){    
    let idVer = () =>{
        let num = 0;
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*100+1);
        
        if(random < 5) {
            num = 1;
        } else if (random < 20 ) {
            num = 2;
        } else if (random < 40) {
            num = 3;
        } else if (random < 60) {
            num = 4;
        } else {
            num = 5;  
        }
            return num;
    }

    let idItem = allPrizes.find((item) => item.id == idVer())

    return `Felicidades, te ganaste ${idItem.articulo} ${idItem.nombre} !! `
}
```

}

Así lo llamo

```
    let mostrarPremio = () =>{ 
    allPrizes.forEach((e) => { 
        document.getElementById('premios').innerHTML = `${e.probabilidad()}`
    })
};
```

Asi lleno allPrize

```
const allPrizes = [];

const gasha1 = new Prize ({id: 1, nombre: "Anana", articulo: "un", img: 40, cantidad: 10, categoria: "frutas"})
const gasha2 = new Prize ({id: 2, nombre: "Sandia", articulo: "una", img: 50, cantidad: 15, categoria: "frutas"})
const gasha3 = new Prize ({id: 3, nombre: "Naranja", articulo: "una", img: 70, cantidad: 20, categoria: "frutas"})
const gasha4 = new Prize ({id: 4, nombre: "Frutilla", articulo: "una", img: 80, cantidad: 15, categoria: "frutas"})
const gasha5 = new Prize ({id: 5, nombre: "Mandarina", articulo: "una", img: 90, cantidad: 20, categoria: "frutas"})

allPrizes.push(gasha1, gasha2, gasha3, gasha4, gasha5)
```

Este es el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes hacer un console.log(data.articulo)? Tiene pinta que no recibes la información deseada.

Comment: ¿y el html de esto donde esta?  Si no pones un [example] válido nos va a costar mucho ayudarte

Comment: En el primer punto entran datos, después asignas los atributos de tu objeto a los datos que llegan, si estos datos llegan vacío, la asigación al atributo será None o undefined, y si no hay valor en el atributo del objeto, al acceder a el da error. Como menciona @MANZARBEITIA, revisa los datos de entrada con "console.log()" en el comienzo del constructor

Comment: Yo creo que el problema esta en como estás llenando el array de allPrizes... podrías agregar ese código?

Comment: @Pipe Ahi subi el codigo, gracias por a ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de tu código es que estás llamando a la función idVer desde dentro del propio find, lo que significa que estás recalculando el id que quieres con cada iteración.

Cambia:

```
let idItem = allPrizes.find((item) => item.id == idVer())
```

Por:

```
let ver = idVer()
let idItem = allPrizes.find((item) => item.id == ver)
```

Comment: Ahi funciono! Muchas gracias @laura_morillo !!